# Oracle add consecutive rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as:

```
Emp_id        Emp_Name    Department     Score  
123           Raju            D1          300
124           Ravi            D2          400
125           Annie           D3          600
126           Ajay            D4          200
127           Amey            D5          500
128           Akil            D6          100
```

I need output as

Sum of Score of row1 and row2 in row1
Sum of Score of row1,row2 and row3 in row2,
and so on
So the output should be:

```
700
1300
1500
2000
2100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want a cumulative sum.  You can use the cumulative sum functionality in SQL;

```
select t.*, sum(t.score) over (order by t.empid)
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me...